# Where there any 'famous people' in the American Southwest before 1500?

Tags: native-americans, famous-people

I teach secondary history classes. For my American Southwest history class, I am required to teach a lesson on 'famous people before 1500'
in the Southwest, i.e. famous people before the Spanish came. After much digging, the only person I've only found one: Nááhwíilbiihí. Are there any others?

The exact terminology used is

> Analyze who have been key figures that have contributed to an individual culture and what they did.

and is a sub-category of *Pueblos and Tribes (c. 1200 BCE–c. 1500 CE)*.

Comment: That's a really strange assignment, are you sure you're understood correctly? I don't think there are any written records from back then? Nááhwíilbiihí is a mythical person or god from what it looks like.

Comment: The exact terminology used is `Analyze who have been key figures that have contributed to an individual culture and what they did.` and is a sub-category of `Pueblos and Tribes (c. 1200 BCE–c. 1500 CE)`.

Comment: AFAIK there were no written records from Native Americans before the Spanish came. And oral tradition makes for very poor historical data.

Comment: For the purposes of your assignment, assume that "famous person" means "anybody we have heard of today". If knowledge of you lasts 500 years you can assume you are pretty famous.

Comment: @Village, please don't modify the question in comments; it decreases the probability & quality of the answer.  A citation for the Navajo god of gambling as a person would be appropriate.  (That's the only reference I found for the name you mention)

Comment: Are you sure that only named individuals qualify? "Key" is not necessarily equivalent to "famous". What about categories such as shamans/priests, hunters, chiefs. Or roles - mother, negotiator, warrior.

Comment: @SJuan76 - Well, there were actually written records down in Mesoamerica (so not the American Southwest), but the Spanish, and to some extent the Aztecs, were [fairly energetic in destroying them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_script#History). In any event, knowledge of how to read them was lost and they weren't deciphered again until quite recently.

Comment: I do not know if this will be acceptable to the good people who gave you this "assignment,"  but if I were you, I would teach a class explaining to the students how little do we know about individuals in the territory of the modern US prior to 1500, why do we know so little and, in particular, why we do not know the name of a single person from that period.

Comment: @Brian Z This assignment seems to be from *New Mexico Social Studies Standards*, item 7.48 on p. 56 in the [draft copy](https://webnew.ped.state.nm.us/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/21-15540-Draft-NM-Standards-For-Teachers-PRE-RULE-VERSION-8_31_21-508-fmt.pdf) Google found. I fail to see how this can be interpreted differently from what the asker presented here. I am as puzzled as the asker given the context "The Emergence of Pueblos and Tribes (c. 1200 BCE – c. 1500 CE)" and the wider context being the history of New Mexico. Maybe a mistake that was fixed in the final version of the document?

Comment: I located what I believe to be the [finalized version](https://webnew.ped.state.nm.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/7th-Grade-SS-NMIS-.pdf) of the new New Mexico standards, and the item mentioned by the asker is still there, as item 7.35 on p. 29 of the PDF covering grade 7. The document provides example content and cross-referencing for many of the items it lists, but (best I can tell) not this one. Strange. I suspect a cut & paste error with content carried over from item 7.55 in the same PDF.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think that would be a good answer to OPs question, especially if you can give a little background or sources why we don't know the name of a single person from that period.